# Static Single Assignment for variables in different scopes

Tags: compiler-construction, scope

I am a student learning Compilers, and I am now confused by a problem in SSA form.

As in many languages, like C, there exists many scopes. A variable in the current scope may be modified in other scopes, for example, the value of a global variables can be changed after calling a function, which makes some optimization incorrect. Furthermore, a variable in the current scope can be modified using pointers.

What should we deal with such circumstance?

Comment: I'm unclear on your exact question.  I'm going to hazard a guess... what you need to know is that every assigment, or implicit or explicit side effect produces a new "lifetime" (aka "single assignment").   What the phi gates do is combine different lifetimes where those lifetimes can reach a shared use.

Answer (score 2):

The simple, conservative solution to the problem you are describing involves never keeping copies of a value if it may change in ways that are difficult or impossible to reason about.

So what exactly do I mean by that? Consider the following C fragment:

```
void bar(void);
int unsafe;

void foo(void) {
    unsafe++; // 1
    bar();
    printf("%d\n", unsafe); // 2
}
```

Assume that this code is compiled using a compiler that performs no [interprocedural optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) or analysis. Clearly, then, it is impossible for the compiler to know whether or not the call to `bar` will mutate `unsafe`. As such, the compiler must not keep a copy of `unsafe` live across the call to `bar`. Instead, the value should be read from and immediately written back to memory at point #1, and read from memory at point #2.

Bottom line: If you cannot definitively prove that it's safe to keep a copy of a global variable live during some portion of the program's execution, it must be read from and/or written to memory every time it is accessed.

A similar problem arises with pointers to local variables, as you suggested:

```
void qux(void) {
    int x;
    int *px = &x;
    x = 10;
    *px = 100;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

A naïve compiler, failing to detect that `x` is [aliased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)), may incorrectly output 10 instead of 100. The conservative solution is similar here: If you have a local variable whose address is taken, *never* keep a copy around -- always spill it to the [stack frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and load/store its value as needed. Besides, you have to do this anyway in order for `x` to even *have* an address in the first place!

Notice that there's nothing specific to SSA form here. The problems, and their solutions, are similar regardless of whether your intermediate representation is in SSA form or not.